# Handle event batch in eventhub triggered azure function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions

Am writing a event publisher and consumer. From the publisher am trying to send events as batch using `eventhub_client.send_batch(batch)`

Now in the consumer side am receiving event and using

```
    if e.get_body() is not None:
    try:
        str = e.get_body().decode("utf-8")
        msg = ast.literal_eval(str)
        props = e.metadata.get('Properties')
        do_something(msg, props)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I have 2 issues

1. will i receive a batch OR single event when i ran consumer (publisher published a batch with 10 events)
2. Am i handling all the events in consumer? am not sure weather my consumer process all the 10 events.

Can somebody clarify the above questions and help me to refine the consumer code if any better way to handle events (am not sure of ast.literal_eval(str) function why has to be used as i got a sample code from some site)

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on how you are receiving events, i.e., if you are using [`receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-python#azure-eventhub-aio-eventhubconsumerclient-receive) or [`receive_batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-python#azure-eventhub-aio-eventhubconsumerclient-receive-batch) method on the [`EventHubConsumerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-python) class.

Based on your code, I suppose you are using `receive`, so your handler would process events one-by-one.

Check the official samples for [`receive`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/recv_async.py#L58) and [`receive_batch`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/receive_batch_with_checkpoint_async.py#L50) for more information on how you can leverage either one.